# Setup API Get Device Properties

Tags: c++, windows, device

I understand how to use the setup api in windows, however, I can't seem to figure out how to obtain everything I need. I want to obtain and know how to for device friendly name, manufacturer, and description. However, I can't seem to figure out how to get the device path so I can call create file. Can somebody point me in to the right direction?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: What's the difference in a device interface and a device instance?

Comment: @CalebMerchant: A device instance represents a function. A device interface is the connection. A USB mouse is an HID device instance, but it has an interface instance that represents its connection to the USB.

Answer (score 0):

I understand answers that only link to off-site are bad form but this topic is rather deep. It also happens that there is a Microsoft article on *exactly* what was asked: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/using-setupapi-to-access-device-properties--windows-vista-and-later-.

Below is a snippet that will return the device path of all devices specified by a GUID (include at least `initguid.h` and then a device-specific header, e.g. `usbiodef.h`). This should give you a general idea of how the SetupAPI works. The device's path is a string which can be passed to `CreateFile` to create a handle suitable for use with `DeviceIoControl`.

```
vector<wstring> EnumDevices(
    _In_    const GUID Guid
)
{
    vector<wstring> r;

    int index = 0;
    HDEVINFO hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&Guid, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);

    SP_DEVINFO_DATA DevInfoData;
    memset(&DevInfoData, 0, sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA));
    DevInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);

    while (SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, index, &DevInfoData)) {
        index++;

        int jndex = 0;
        SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA DevIntData;
        memset(&DevIntData, 0, sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA));
        DevIntData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);

        while (SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(
            hDevInfo,
            &DevInfoData, &Guid, jndex, &DevIntData
        )) {
            jndex++;

            // Get the size required for the structure.
            DWORD RequiredSize;
            SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
                hDevInfo, &DevIntData, NULL, NULL, &RequiredSize, NULL
            );

            PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA pDevIntDetData = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)malloc(
                sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA) + RequiredSize
            );
            memset(pDevIntDetData, 0, sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA) + RequiredSize);
            pDevIntDetData->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

            SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
                hDevInfo,
                &DevIntData,
                pDevIntDetData, RequiredSize,
                NULL,
                &DevInfoData
            );

            r.push_back(wstring(pDevIntDetData->DevicePath));
            free(pDevIntDetData);
        }
    }

    return r;
}
```